# is_front_page is not working in my functions.php

Tags: php, functions

is_front_page() in the below code is not working... this function just doesn't run when I'm on the front page, any idea why? am I doing something wrong?

```
function save_landing_page_slider()
{
    
        if (isset($_GET['slider']) && is_front_page()) {
                $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
                $slider = $_GET['slider'];
                update_field('user_landing_slider', $slider, 'user_'.$current_user_id);
        }
   
   
}
add_action('init', 'save_landing_page_slider', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> add_action('init', 'save_landing_page_slider', 10, 2);
> ```

*`init` is too early* — if you look at the [WordPress query overview on Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview), `init` is (as of writing) the second step, whereas `is_` variables like `$is_page` (or `WP_Query::$is_page`) that are used by conditional tags like `is_front_page()` are only set in step 4, so instead of `init`, you should use a later hook like [`wp`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/) or [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/):

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'save_landing_page_slider' );
```

So in order for conditional tags to work properly, make sure to call them in the right hook or place.

Additionally, you should also understand when would [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/#description) return true, e.g. when your homepage is set to a [static Page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-static-front-page/), and that you're on the homepage.

Comment: Thanks for explaining everything